# Adding a div at a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show

I am trying to show an id at a certain point. I looked at other examples from here and modeled mine just like one. However, my id is not displaying once I get to the scroll point and I am not sure. The id I want to show `mobile-transparent`, I have set the position to absolute and added a `z-index` to try to troubleshoot that.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mobile-transparent").hide(); //hide your div initially
    var topOfOthDiv = $("#green").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $("#mobile-transparent").show(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#blue, #red, #green {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
}
#red {
  background: red;
}
#green {
  background: green;
}
#mobile-transparent {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  right: 5%;
}

.mobile-down-button {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="mobile-transparent">
  <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/mobile_menu_white.png" class="mobile-down-button" alt="menu" height="35px" width="35px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `position:fixed` instead `position:absolute;`.

Because `position:absolute` set it to particular position given. Not display when you scroll.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mobile-transparent").hide(); //hide your div initially
    var topOfOthDiv = $("#green").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
  
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) {
       $('#mobile-transparent').fadeIn();
     } else {
       $('#mobile-transparent').fadeOut();
     }
       
    });
});
```

```css
#blue, #red, #green {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
}
#red {
  background: red;
}
#green {
  background: green;
}
#mobile-transparent {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  right: 5%;
}

.mobile-down-button {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="mobile-transparent">
  <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/mobile_menu_white.png" class="mobile-down-button" alt="menu" height="35px" width="35px">
</div>
```

Comment: Is that all you did because it still won't work in my jsfiddle? How can I get this to only show when at that point and beyond? If the user isn't scrolled at green or past, it show nothing?

Comment: @Paul You mean if user scroll back to top. You don't want to show?

Comment: well I'm sure that is just this : `if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $("#mobile-transparent").show(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
        } else {
          $("#mobile-transparent").hide();
        }` .... but this isn't showing in my jsfiddle. Not sure why.

Comment: Nevermind the lagging. I put the JS file in the header and that fixed it, but it still displays on page load.

Comment: @Paul It is working here check.https://jsfiddle.net/be1zf3L1/. It looks like your JQuery not workin.

Comment: Right. I went a different route. So I guess this may answer my question. If I am using `$("#mobile-transparent").hide(); //hide your div initially`, but the `#mobile-transparent` is still showing, then obviously I am in the scroll point. So how can I get it to stay hidden until the top of the screen is at that scroll point?

Comment: or if I can get it to show up after a div. Is that possible?

Comment: @Paul Put JQuery plugines before your JQuery code. Or to hide initially Use `display:none` in css. https://jsfiddle.net/be1zf3L1/1/.

Comment: I can't believe I hadn't noticed that earlier. This "Put JQuery plugines before your JQuery code." did it. Thanks for all of the help!!

Comment: @Paul glad to help. And don't forgot to mark it as answer.